# Равномерное расположение последовательного списка

Tags: html

Все привет, есть проблема с выводом списка в 3 колонки, с сервера приходит отсортированный список по буквенно, его нужно вывести равномерно в 3 колонки в формате

```
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
4 8 12
```

Для этого я использовал простое свойсто column-count:3; но он отображает немного не корректно как видно на скриншоте последние 2 элемента прибило вправо, как можно решить данную проблему? Вообще когда оно выводиться так не сильно большая проблема [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на этих скриншотах показано когда элемента всего 2 или 1

2 элемента
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 Элемент 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @sargo111 Выложите пожалуйста разметку html и стиль css, чтобы можно было детально ответить на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос был решён, все дело было в том что элементы имели margin-top:; свойство column-count как-то не корректно с ним сотрудничает) проблема решилась после того как убрал margin-top и добавил min-height для создания видимости отступа